# Destructing a Single shared_ptr One-by-One

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, explicit-destructor-call

I am attempting to destruct a shared_ptr one-by-one, yet when I destruct the last pointer, the use_count() goes nuts. Observe my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


int main() {

    int * val = new int(5);
    std::shared_ptr<int> myPtr = std::make_shared<int>(*val);

    myPtr.~__shared_ptr();

}
```

Will produce the following output in the debugger:

```
myPtr value: 5  myPtr.use_count():8787448 // Or some other large int
```

I was hoping on the final destruction it would set the use_count() to 0 and deallocate the memory for the integer. It appears none of this is happening.

I could if() statement this when the use_count() == 1, but this seems very inelegant. Does anyone know of another solution?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: We're implementing cluster classing, where clusters can point to the same point in the universe. When a cluster is destructed, we don't want the point to go anywhere until the last shared_ptr is being deleted.

Comment: There's just far too much code in the Cluster itself to paste here, and we've narrowed it down to this issue in the debugger.

Comment: Everything you are doing here is dangerous.

Comment: If you want to find out whether the pointed to object has been deallocated, then just use a class whose destructor prints a message. What you're doing now with manually calling the pointer's destructor and then accessing it afterwards is most likely UB.

Comment: In that context, the shared_ptr returning garbage makes sense. The memory continuing to be allocated to the integer does not.

Comment: Also, what is `__shared_ptr`?

Comment: What you're seeing doesn't prove the memory is still allocated. You could be (and probably are) accessing deallocated memory and reading whatever happens to be there, which could be the bytes that were left behind from that `int` and haven't been re-used _yet_.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish I was afraid of that - unfortunately, it looks like we'll have to come up with a solution other than shared_ptr.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish - I've been watching it in the debugger too and it doesn't appear to release.

Comment: Why not just let it go out of scope and check its count through a second `shared_ptr`?

Comment: @Galik I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Miller "_Edited out the UB_" You have not. You have removed some UB not all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91274/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-miller).

Comment: The memory you allocate for the integer in `val` is leaked in your example. It is not managed by the shared pointer.

Comment: I would like to see the tag "Zombies" added to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured out what you are after. You want to detect when the use count of the shared object is zero.

The way this is done is using a [std::weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) that is designed to work *with* the [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) so you can keep track of whether or not the object has been destroyed.

Here:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // weak_ptr is only convertable to a shared_ptr if the shared_ptr
    // usage count is > 0
    std::weak_ptr<int> wp;

    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(5);
        wp = ptr; // link weak_ptr to shared_ptr

        if(auto sp = wp.lock()) // try to convert weak_ptr to shared_ptr
        {
            // if we get here use_count was > 0
            std::cout << "Before: use count > 0: "
                << std::boolalpha << (sp.use_count() > 0) << '\n';
        }
        else
        {
            // if we get here use_count was == 0
            std::cout << "Before: Destroyed\n";
        }
        // ptr goes out of scope here
    }

    if(auto sp = wp.lock()) // try to convert weak_ptr to shared_ptr
    {
        // if we get here use_count was > 0
        std::cout << "After: use count > 0: "
            << std::boolalpha << (sp.use_count() > 0) << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        // if we get here use_count was == 0
        std::cout << "After: Destroyed\n";
    }
}
```

Basically, if the linked [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) still holds a reference to the object then the *associated* [std::weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) can be converted to a [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) using [std::weak_ptr::lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock). If that fails then the *associated* [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is no longer pointing at the shared object - it has been destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

> I am attempting to destruct a shared_ptr one-by-one,

I have no idea what that means, but ...

```
myPtr.~__shared_ptr();
```

Never, ever, ever do this.

You are running the destructor for an automatic object, i.e. one that lives on the stack and will be destroyed automatically by the compiler when it goes out of scope. By destroying it manually you cause it to be destroyed twice. You cannot end an object's lifetime twice, it is not James Bond, it only lives once.

Destroying the same object twice is undefined behaviour. That means weird things can happen. Asking why you get weird results from a program with undefined behaviour is a waste of time. Weird things happen when you have undefined behaviour **because you have undefined behaviour**. Anything can happen. You should be thankful it's only weird, and not catastrophic.

The standard specifically points out this exact scenario is undefined behaviour, in 12.4 [class.dtor]:

> Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists; the behavior is undefined if the
>   destructor is invoked for an object whose lifetime has ended (3.8). *[Example:* if the destructor for an
>   automatic object is explicitly invoked, and the block is subsequently left in a manner that would ordinarily
>   invoke implicit destruction of the object, the behavior is undefined. *— end example]*

Even worse, you are running the destructor for a base class of `myPtr` so you are only destroying *part* of the object. That means you have an object where part of it is dead and part of it is alive, and then at the end of the scope part of it gets killed again. Under no circumstances can that ever be the right thing to do. Ever.

> I was hoping on the final destruction it would set the use_count() to 0 and deallocate the memory for the integer. It appears none of this is happening.

Your conclusion is wrong. It probably is happening, but if the object is destroyed and the memory is deallocated then trying to look at it produces nonsense results. You can't ask a zombie what its name is, it will reply "BRAINZZZZ!" instead of telling you anything useful. And eat your brains. Now you are dead. Don't play with zombies.

Also, as Neil Kirk comments above, this is also wrong:

```
int * val = new int(5);
std::shared_ptr<int> myPtr = std::make_shared<int>(*val);
```

You create an `int` on the heap, then you create *copy* of it on the heap that will be managed by a `shared_ptr`. The `shared_ptr` owns an `int` which has the same value as `*val` but nothing owns `val` so that will be a memory leak. You probably meant to do either this:

```
int * val = new int(5);
std::shared_ptr<int> myPtr(val);
```

or more likely this:

```
int val = 5;
std::shared_ptr<int> myPtr = std::make_shared<int>(val);
```